# Python regular expression find all patterns and get the minium values from the extracted patterns?

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I am new to regular expression.I have string like below

'
"Light Vines, Hearts and Flowers Decorate your room with colorful light vines! Watch dancing, **Age Group: 2 Yrs/3 to 4 Years/5 to 6 Years/7 to 8 Years** multicolored lights come to life on 10 feet of vine! Customize your vine with attachable leaves and two styles of interchangeable light covers.   Light Vines, Hearts and Flowers:   **Age Range: 6 years and up 10'** long string of beautiful lights Multiple light effects fade in and out, constantly changing 8 different  **Less Than 1 Year** light designs Features beautiful hearts and flowers Decorate your light string with puffy leaf attachments  Decorate your room with **Age start: 6 yrs and up 10'** colorful light vines! Watch dancing, multicolored lights come to life on 10 feet of vine! Customize **Age Group: 2 Years/3 to 4 Years/5 to 6 mnth/7 to 8 month**

your vine with attachable leaves and two styles of interchangeable light covers.

Here is the two step process:

step 1:

```
Find the pattern (below I mentioned all possible cases).

Step 2 :

Find the minimum value of age from the extracted pattern
```

I tried below regex for all possible cases which are present in my data set.

Some regex are not giving proper output.

```
############# Re => \bAGE[a-z]\b[\w\s]*\W+\d+.*?(?:month|year)) ##############

    case 1:

    Age Group: 2 Years/3 to 4 Years/5 to 6 Years/7 to 8 month **output=> 7 month**  
    Age Group: -2 Years/3 to 4 Years **output=> 2 years**
    Age Range: -2 To 4 Years/5 To 7 Years/8 To 11 Years **output=>  2 years**
    Age Range: 6 years and up  **output=>  6 years**
    Age Start: -6 Years **output=> 6 years**
    Age: -3 - 5 Years **output=> 3 years**
    aged 1-5 years  **output=>  1 years**
    ages 4 and up **output =>  4**
    Age: 3 - 5 Years  **output=> 3 years**
    aged 1-5 years  **output=> 1 years**
    ages 4 and up **output=>  4**


 case 2:
   5 years of age  =>  (\d+[\w\s][year[s]?|month[s]?)*.[\w\s]OF[\w\s]AGE)
   4 month of age

 **output=> 4 month**

case 3:
adults 15 and up  => (\badult[s]?.\b[\w\s]\d+)    **output=> 15**


case 4:
12 month and up    output=>  12 month

6 years and up  =>  (\b\d*?.y[year[s]?|month[s]?.[\w\s]and[w\s]up[\w\s])

  **output=> 6 years**

case 5:
for age 5 and up =>  (\bFOR[\w\s]AGE?.[\w\s]*.\d\b)

**output=>  5**

case 6:
six years of age and older  => ([a-z]+\syear?.[\w\s]of[\w\s]age.)

 **output =>  six years**

case 7:
Less Than 1 Year    **output=>  1 year**
```

My final aim is to find the minimum age from each after extracting these patterns from the text.

The problem i am facing that values are contains unit as 'years' and 'months' . How do I handle these problem.

Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand. What is your expected output?

Comment: please post your expected output

Comment: I expected output is the cases which I mentioned and from those I need to extract the minimum value i.e. age. As you can see it contains 'years or months so extracting minimum  out of that is bit tricky.These are all possible cases I need to cover so I wrote different patterns for each possible cases. Which is not exactly giving me the expected output.

Comment: My apologies. I edited the question with the output.  I want to extract the pattern first which I mentioned in the cases and get the minimum from that pattern.

Comment: How is `2 Years/3 to 4 Years/5 to 6 Years/7 to 8 month **output=> 2 years**` true when you want the minimum age value....shouldn't the output be `7 to 8 month`?

Comment: sorry. yes you are right. It should be 7 month. I didn't see. I edited.